# What does NSExpression *lhs, and NSExpression *rhs mean?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I know what an NSExpression is, but all over the place I see these cryptographic variable names like lhs and rhs.

Yes, I can guess it means something leftFoo and rightFoo, but what does "hs" stand for? No idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Left-hand side" and "right-hand side". The left-hand side is on the left of the comparison operator, and the right-hand side is on the right.

Answer (score 2):

"**left-hand side**" and "**right-hand side**" (of the expression's operator).

> This abbreviation is seldom if ever used in print; it is very informal. ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-hand_side_and_right-hand_side_of_an_equation))

Apparently API docs are very informal, too :)