# What does Unable to generate SQL for predicate (_STRING PREDICATE_) (problem on RHS) mean?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I'm trying to develop an app for iPhone using Core Data and I'm using a very basic predicate to grab objects. (i.e. attribute_name==string)

I've checked the model to make sure the attribute names are correct and I know from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072338/what-does-nsexpression-lhs-and-nsexpression-rhs-mean) that RHS means "Right Hand Side," which leads me to the "string" part. I'm creating the format string using

```
NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"attribute_name==%@", string];
```

Then to fetch, I'm using this:

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:_entityName inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *array = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

What am I missing? What could cause this error to occur?

Thanks.

Comment: what does your string contain?

Comment: The string contains another string object from an array expanded using fast enumeration. So it looks like this: `for (NSString *stringInArray in array) { NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"attribute_name==%@", stringInArray]; }` Thanks for the quick response @bbum!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to quote the string if you really want to use the `NSString stringWithFormat:` message or you could use the `NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:` message with the formatting and arguments because it will "do the right thing" with the rhs in your situation (I would suggest that you use the `NSPredicate` method without the quotes)

```
NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"attribute_name==\"%@\"", string];
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot @BrentPriddy! I'm not 100% on why this worked though seeing I thought the quotes were added automatically when you use substitution: `String constants must be quoted within the expression—single and double quotes are both acceptable, but must be paired appropriately (that is, a double quote (") does not match a single quote (')). If you use variable substitution using %@ (such as firstName like %@), the quotation marks are added for you automatically.`I really appreciate the help though!

Comment: They are only added automatically if you are using the NSPredicate predicateWithFormat method. You were using the NSString stringWithFormat method which is not really the right way to use formulate predicates

Answer (score 19):

You're doing this wrong.  You should not be creating a format string.

I'm guessing (based on your reaction to @Brent's answer) that you're doing something like this:

```
NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"foo == \"%@\"", bar];
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
```

**Don't do that**.

Do this instead:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"foo == %@", bar];
```

The first will fail if `bar` happens to contain a `"` character.  The second will not.

Comment: I can see why a " character would break the first example, but I don't totally understand why the first one works for me and the second does not. To be clear, why does the first one work only when using escaped quotes?